# Using Fermat's Theorem compute ..

Tags: elementary-number-theory

```
 So here goes the problem :

 Compute:
 2^1234 (mod 11) 
 How would I go about trying to solve this ?
```

This is what I have tried so far
     I know that 2^10 (mod 11) is congruent to 1,but that is about it.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* You're in the right direction. Write $2^{1234} = (2^{10})^{123}\cdot2^4$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

As an immediate consequence of *lil' Fermat*, for any integer $a$ not divisible by $11$, one has:
$$a^n\equiv a^{n\bmod 10}\mod 11.$$